# How do i view information of bmp image

Tags: bitmap

Im new to c++ and its developing. I'm going to develop image based algorithm. in order to do that i wish to use .bmp (bitmap image). i want to grab the pixel values of that image to compare with other pixel values of another bmp image. to do that i followed [Wiki link -bitmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) there i have noticed that there are other info of bitmap as well.

My problem is how do i take a information of the my bitmap image. The above link they mentioned some are optional , how do i see in my image all the sections such as Color Table, Extra bit masks etc. please help me thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer the following PDF. It will help you.

http://www.di.unito.it/~marcog/SM/BMPformat-Wiki.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/

However, I don't think bitmaps have a "color table", that's more of a GIF thing.  Bitmaps just describe (typically 8-bit each) RGB(A) values.